# Can I host multiple map services from a single file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-server, file-geodatabase, map-service

Can I host and consume multiple map services from a single file geodatabase?

The data will be view only. Feature service capability will not be turned on, so no editing will be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't, are you having specific issues with it?  The File Geodatabase format supports multiple, simultaneous, view-only connections, so there shouldn't be any issue with you doing that with map services.
You can see more info about comparisons between database types in ESRI at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000007000000

Hope that helps.